# php && mysql about Post method

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I submit the data to post[submit] and post[request] from two different buttons.

I submitted user_id to post[submit] but i am unable to echo the user_id in request portion (post[request])

/* passing the data from two different form*/

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['request']) ){            
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "submit working ";
        $user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
        echo $user_id; /* this id passed from submit form*/
    }
    else{
        echo "Request Portion Working";
        echo $user_id;  /*this line gives the error*/
    }            
}

I submit the data to post[submit] and post[request] from two different buttons.
I submitted user_id to post[submit] but i am unable to echo the user_id in request portion (post[request])
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['request']) ){

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['request']) ){
    $user_id= $_POST['user_id'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       echo "submit working ";
       echo $user_id; /* this id passed from submit form*/
    }else{
       echo "Request Portion Working";
       echo $user_id;  /*this line gives the error*/
    }

}
```

Comment: it still not working i  tried

Comment: what error your getting..

Comment: Notice: Undefined index error

Comment: There your not posting  "user_id" in post variable. print "$_POST" in your code and check what all are variables posting. possible provide HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

While calling a variable in a function you need to make sure that it is in scope. Else it would not be recognized.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['request']) ){
    if(isset($_POST['user_id']) {
      $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         echo "submit working ";
         echo $user_id; /* this id passed from submit form*/
      } else {
         echo "Request Portion Working";
         echo $user_id;  /*this line gives the error*/
      }  
    } else {
        echo 'User_Id not set';
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index error,  Yes the said user_id not set; but it has been passed from the form , it working in only submit portion , but not in request portion

Comment: Can you reproduce the exact error generated?

Answer (score 0):

in your code when `$_POST['request']` send then you do not `$_POST['user_id']` so get your user_id for any condition so you use this all condition, you can use also trim to remove space

```
<?php
$user_id = ''; // assign variable 
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['request']) ){
     $user_id= trim($_POST['user_id']); // get your user_id for any condition so you use this all condition, you can use also trim to remove space
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "submit working ";
        echo $user_id; /* this id passed from submit form*/
    }
    else{
        echo "Request Portion Working";
        echo $user_id;  /*this line gives the error*/
    }            
} else {
     echo "No Post request";
}
```